# using async/await in IF statement

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor. I am currently writing a automation test using protractor to check if an element is enabled and perform on action only when the element is enabled. Following is my code. I want to use async / await but the test never gets inside the loop when i use async await. But the test passes even without  executing.  Please help.

```
if (await this.button.isEnabled()) {
  await this.text.sendKeys('abc');
  await this.send.click();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the button is not enabled? Did you try checking what value it returns?

Comment: the button is enabled. But the problem is execution never goes inside the loop if i use async await.

Comment: Write your code like this: `var isEnabled = await this.button.isEnabled(); if(isEnabled){...}` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: doesn't work that way. Test execution never gets into the loop.

Comment: So it means that either `isEnabled` returns `false` or `isEnabled` is not awaitable and doesn't return a promise. Side note, `if` statement is not a loop.

Comment: Yep sorry i mean IF statement and not loop :).

Comment: I guess isEnabled is not awaitable.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled). Your button must be disabled, because it in fact returns a promise. Look if the button even exists before you check `isEnabled`. Can you get anything from that button? e.g. `getText()`? Does it even exist?

Answer (score 4):

for synchronizing if block and logic after if block.
create an async function with the if logic inside it. like following

```html
async a(){
  async function b() {
    if(condition){ 
      //await async call
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(function(){
            resolve("successful");
          }, 10000);
        });
      }
  }
  await b(); 
  console.log('now');
  //post if synchronous logic 
}
```

In above code "now" will be printed only after 10 secs. if you remove **await** before **b()**, "now" will be printed instantly before those 10 secs are over.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to declare your function `async`? This worked for me on my app:

```
async function doStuff() {
  if (await page.button.isEnabled()) {
    console.log('enabled');
  } else {
    console.log('disabled');
  }
}

doStuff();
```

This is unlikely necessary (I didn't need it), but in case you are running an older version of Protractor, you might have to disable the [Selenium Promise Manager](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/simplify-protractor-web-tests-with-async-and-await/) in your `protractor.config`:

```
exports.config = { 
  ...
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  ... 
};
```

Comment: This fails when element is not enabled. As there are scenarios where the element is not enabled.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood, sorry. See my edited answer.